# Regular Expressions - match pattern but return subpattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a pattern (using java programming), but I need only parts of it.

Example... from the following text:

```
0 - Amount: 3 - Class 29
1 - Amount: 2 - Class 21
2 - Amount: 11 - Class 1
```

I want to match the pattern "Amount: \d* - Class \d*", but return only the pairs of numbers, so that the output is something like an array:

```
{
    {3, 29},
    {2, 21},
    {11, 1}
}
```

Can I do it using something implemented in java regular expressions? I think searching the matched strings is unnecessary, regex seems to have something ready for this kind of problem.

And... do regular expressions (in general, not only java regular expressions) have a tool for it so that no much additional programming is necessary to extract the information from the matched strings? It is possible for me to switch the programming language, if some other regex implementation is better than java's for this job.

Comment: Java regex supports capturing groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to use capturing groups by using parentheses in your regex:

```
Amount: (\d*) - Class (\d*)
        ^--^-- Here---^---^
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC4sU3/2)**

Then you have to grab the content from them with `\1` and `\2`. In java you have to use the `matcher.group(n)`. For instance, you can have a code like this:

```
String str = "0 - Amount: 3 - Class 29\n1 - Amount: 2 - Class 21\n2 - Amount: 11 - Class 1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Amount: (\\d*) - Class (\\d*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{");
while (matcher.find()){
    sb.append(String.format("{%s, %s},", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)));
}
sb.setLength(sb.length()-1); // remove last comma
sb.append("}");

System.out.println(sb.toString())
```

**[Full IdeOne code](https://ideone.com/04lVus)**

Comment: This is also matching the word `Class` in the second capture group. I think he just wants the numbers.

Comment: @m_callens sorry, had a typo. Was updating the answer with some code. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: Got it! The name of the feature is "capturing groups". And I just learned about the online regex tester and language compiler. Thanks!!!

Comment: @EduardoPoço, yes... you can learn more on http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html